# how to track score gains in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to display a players current score as well as how many points they have gained within a selected time frame.

I have 2 tables

skills table

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id |  name   |     created_at      |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | skill 1 | 2020-06-05 00:00:00 |
|  2 | skill 2 | 2020-06-05 00:00:00 |
|  3 | skill 3 | 2020-06-05 00:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

scores table

```
+----+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+
| id | player_id | skill_id | score |     created_at      |
+----+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 |        1 |     5 | 2020-06-06 00:00:00 |
|  2 |         1 |        1 |    10 | 2020-07-06 00:00:00 |
|  3 |         1 |        2 |     1 | 2020-07-06 00:00:00 |
|  4 |         2 |        1 |    11 | 2020-07-06 00:00:00 |
|  5 |         1 |        1 |    13 | 2020-07-07 00:00:00 |
|  6 |         1 |        2 |    10 | 2020-07-07 00:00:00 |
|  7 |         2 |        1 |    12 | 2020-07-07 00:00:00 |
|  8 |         1 |        1 |    20 | 2020-07-08 00:00:00 |
|  9 |         1 |        2 |    15 | 2020-07-08 00:00:00 |
| 10 |         2 |        1 |    17 | 2020-07-08 00:00:00 |
+----+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

my expected results are:-

24 hour query

```
+-----------+---------+-------+------+
| player_id |  name   | score | gain |
+-----------+---------+-------+------+
|         1 | skill 1 |    20 |    7 |
|         1 | skill 2 |    15 |    5 |
+-----------+---------+-------+------+
```

7 day query

```
+-----------+---------+-------+------+
| player_id |  name   | score | gain |
+-----------+---------+-------+------+
|         1 | skill 1 |    20 |   10 |
|         1 | skill 2 |    15 |   14 |
+-----------+---------+-------+------+
```

31 day query

```
+-----------+---------+-------+------+
| player_id |  name   | score | gain |
+-----------+---------+-------+------+
|         1 | skill 1 |    20 |   15 |
|         1 | skill 2 |    15 |   14 |
+-----------+---------+-------+------+
```

so far I have the following, but all this does is return the last 2 records for each skill, I am struggling to calculate the gains and the different time frames

```
SELECT player_id, skill_id, name, score 
FROM (SELECT player_id, skill_id, name, score, 
      @skill_count := IF(@current_skill = skill_id, @skill_count + 1, 1) AS skill_count,
      @current_skill := skill_id 
      FROM skill_scores 
      INNER JOIN skills 
        ON skill_id = skills.id 
      WHERE player_id = 1
      ORDER BY skill_id, score DESC
     ) counted 
WHERE skill_count <= 2
```

I would like some help figuring out the query I need to build to get the desired results, or is it best to do this with php instead of in the db?

EDIT:-

MYSQL 8.0.20 dummy data id's are primary_key auto increment but I didnt ad that for simplicity:-

```
CREATE TABLE skills
   (
      id bigint,
      name VARCHAR(80)
   );
   
   CREATE TABLE skill_scores
   (
      id bigint,
      player_id bigint,
      skill_id bigint, 
      score bigint,
      created_at timestamp
   );
 
   INSERT INTO skills VALUES (1, 'skill 1'); 
   INSERT INTO skills VALUES (2, 'skill 2'); 
   INSERT INTO skills VALUES (3, 'skill 3'); 
 
   INSERT INTO skill_scores VALUES (1, 1, 1 , 5, '2020-06-06 00:00:00');
   INSERT INTO skill_scores VALUES (2, 1, 1 , 10, '2020-07-06 00:00:00');
   INSERT INTO skill_scores VALUES (3, 1, 2 , 1, '2020-07-06 00:00:00');
   INSERT INTO skill_scores VALUES (4, 2, 1 , 11, '2020-07-06 00:00:00');
   INSERT INTO skill_scores VALUES (5, 1, 1 , 13, '2020-07-07 00:00:00');
   INSERT INTO skill_scores VALUES (6, 1, 2 , 10, '2020-07-07 00:00:00');
   INSERT INTO skill_scores VALUES (7, 2, 1 , 12, '2020-07-07 00:00:00');
   INSERT INTO skill_scores VALUES (8, 1, 1 , 20, '2020-07-08 00:00:00');
   INSERT INTO skill_scores VALUES (9, 1, 2 , 15, '2020-07-08 00:00:00');
   INSERT INTO skill_scores VALUES (10, 2, 1 , 17, '2020-07-08 00:00:00');
```

Comment: ? Player skill may both grow up and fall down?

Comment: yes, the score can go up and down

Comment: Specify your MySQL version. Add tables' CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts instead /in addition to table-formed example data.

Comment: added at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT id, player_id, skill_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(score) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id, skill_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) score, 
       FIRST_VALUE(score) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id, skill_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) - FIRST_VALUE(score) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id, skill_id ORDER BY created_at ASC) gain,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY player_id, skill_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
FROM skill_scores
WHERE created_at BETWEEN @current_date - INTERVAL @interval DAY AND @current_date
)
SELECT cte.player_id, skills.name, cte.score, cte.gain
FROM cte
JOIN skills ON skills.id = cte.skill_id
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY player_id, name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=52d53410e1dcddead54b0de7f8970fd6)

Ps. I don't understand where `gain=15` is taken for 31-day period - the difference between `'2020-07-08 00:00:00'` and `'2020-06-06 00:00:00'` is `32` days.

Comment: Wow, what a great solution you truly are an SQL ninja! There is a few commands in there that I have never seen before and will have to research, but could you explain what "cte" is? I'm guessing you have created some kind of temporary space and named it "cte"?

Comment: @Chris In general - [WITH (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). In query text - an alias of CTE.

Comment: I have just ran into a small problem with this solution, if I run the same query now (4 days later) and the database has not been updated the query still works off the last results found meaning that for the 1 day interval 0 results are displayed, this would then become a problem for the other intervals if the db wasn't updated for a longer period of time. Is there an easy solution to this? to clarify if you use your fiddle and SET current_date := '2020-07-14';  it should return the same result as if you had SET current_date := '2020-07-09'; is this an easy update to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you need a (temporary) table for this. I will call it "player_skill_gains". Its basically the players skills ordered by created_at and with an auto_incremented id:

```sql
CREATE TABLE player_skill_gains
(`id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
                                          , `player_id` int
                                         , skill_id int
                                         , score int
                                         , created_at date)
;

INSERT INTO player_skill_gains(player_id, skill_id, score, created_at)
SELECT player_skills.player_id AS player_id
  , player_skills.skill_id
  , SUM(player_skills.score) AS score
, player_skills.created_at
FROM player_skills
GROUP BY player_skills.id, player_skills.skill_id, player_skills.created_at
ORDER BY player_skills.player_id, player_skills.skill_id, player_skills.created_at ASC;
```

Using this table we can relatively easily select the last skill for each row (id-1). Using this we can calculate the gains:

```sql
SELECT player_skill_gains.player_id, skills.name, player_skill_gains.score
  , player_skill_gains.score - IFNULL(bef.score,0) AS gain
  , player_skill_gains.created_at
FROM player_skill_gains
  INNER JOIN skills ON player_skill_gains.skill_id = skills.id
  LEFT JOIN player_skill_gains AS bef ON (player_skill_gains.id - 1) = bef.id
      AND player_skill_gains.player_id = bef.player_id
      AND player_skill_gains.skill_id = bef.skill_id
```

For the different queries you want to have (24 hours, 7 days, etc.) you just have to specify the needed where-part for the query.

You can see all this in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1571a8/11/0